# $scope return null objects and undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am fetching ids in `ng-model` from `ng-repeat` and try to get them in `$scope`
but scope returns me null, null on every id as my ids is 659 and 848 so it start from 1 and put null to each id except which is present there.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in items">
<input type="text" name="item_id" ng-model="ItemProd[x.item_id][$index]">
<input type="submit">
<div>
```

Output in console of `console.log($scope.ItemProd);`

```
array(849) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL [4]=> NULL [5]=> NULL [6]=> NULL [7]=> NULL [8]=> NULL [9]=> NULL [10]=> NULL [11]=> NULL [12]=> NULL [13]=> NULL [14]=> NULL [15]=> ...... 
NULL [658]=> NULL [659]=> **object(stdClass)#34 (1) { ["0"]=> string(3) "666"** } [660]=> NULL ......
[841]=> NULL [842]=> NULL [843]=> NULL [844]=> NULL [845]=> NULL [846]=> NULL [847]=> NULL **[848]=> object(stdClass)#35 (1) { ["1"]=> string(3) "777"** } }
```

Comment: Try $scope.ItemProd = []; in controller.

Comment: use it but still null objects

Comment: Can you post your array format here?

Comment: 849) [undefined × 659, Object, undefined × 188, Object]659: Object0: "666"__proto__: Object848: Object1: "777"__proto__: Objectlength: 849__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

In your controller

```
$scope.ItemProd = [];
console.log($scope.ItemProd);
```

Comment: console.log($scope.ItemProd); i am using this in console.log  but why i am recieving empty objects  as i have given just two ids.